# How to fix subtitles overlapping in KM Player?

Tags: video, subtitles, kmplayer

I am trying to watch a movie with subtitles in KMplayer. But subtitles are overlapping making them difficult to read. How can I fix this?

Comment: Usually it's the subs file that's wrong, end time after the next start time - you have to fix the subs file [or find a better source;) Subs files are very very literal.